# CKeditor, colour of text seems to be not retained although HTML is correct, how to resolve?

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.4.5.

Users use the text colour icon to change the colour of a word which works fine. When one checks the underlying HTML, it shows:

```
<p><span style="color:#FF0000">test&nbsp;</span></p>
```

However when clicks the "source" icon again to return to the standard non HTML view, the colouring has gone, although the underlying HTML is still correct. If you take this HTML and render it in a browser it will work correctly. So it seems that CKEditor is not able to render text colour correctly, unless freshly changed using the text colour icon.

We had customers thinking that the colour had not changed, and then trying to fix the issue in the HTML, which resulted in the total corruption of the HTML due to human error.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in the CKE demo? Because I can't and it's hard to help without it. My only guess would be that maybe you have a custom editor css with something like `* { color: #000 !important; }` that would override the rendering but not the underlying code.

Comment: @Nenotlep, thanks for this. Just checked the demo as well, and yes it seems fine. So perhaps there is some erroneous css higher up the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for CKEditor it might so happen that Advanced Content Filter will strip undesired tags / attributes.

If you don't have **colorbutton** plugin, CKEditor will strip this span (see [standard demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#standard)).

You have 2 simple solutions:

### Add colorbutton plugin.

Simply add to your config:

```
    config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
```

### Add ACF proper rule.

```
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'span{color}';
```

For more informations about ACF see [Content Filtering (ACF)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf).