# CKeditor does not seem to be rendering the correct text colour when retrieving data?

Tags: ckeditor

I asked about this question a few months back, but unfortunately it has not solved my issue, so I am asking it again with more information.

I am using CKeditor 4.4.5

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984096/ckeditor-colour-of-text-seems-to-be-not-retained-although-html-is-correct-how)

I have experimented with the online demo of CKeditor. What works is that the colour is rendered when making the edit in CKeditor, however when one retrieves a content with the coloured span element within it, as it correctly should do, the colour is not rendered in CKeditor. Also it seems that tags are not being stripped out at all. It just seems that CKeditor is not rendering something like :

```
<textarea class="RTE" cols="20" disabled="True" id="Content" name="Content" 
rows="2">
&lt;h1&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:red&quot;&gt;I should be coloured red&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
</textarea>
```

with:

```
I should be coloured red
```

in red.

I have checked for "!important", in relevant CSS, and I cannot see any that would affect this text.

Thoughts on why CKeditor is not respecting the "color" attribute of this "span" element when retrieving/displaying data, rather than initially editing it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Source in "source" view:

```
<h1><span style="color:red">I should be coloured red</span></h1>
```

EDIT2

This works:

```
<p style="color:red">I should be coloured red</p>
```

EDIT3

This works

```
<h1 style="color:red">XXX red text XXX</h1>
```

EDIT4

This does not work:

```
<p><span style="color:red">XXX red text XXX<</span></p>
```

Comment: Ok... Can you get us an online example? If this is not ACF and it seems to not be CSS either it's really, really difficult to say.

Comment: Your answer has disappeared..?? The "span" tag and "color" attribute is correct in the "source" view as per EDIT in my question.

Comment: Just been playing with P tag, and it works with this. See EDIT2

Comment: Looks like the embedded "span" tag within the H1 is causing the issue which is the way that CKeditor's colour button designs its HTML.

Comment: Found the cause of the problem, and found the short term answer. It was to do with a config entry I had for SPAN, but unsure why the entry was preventing the correct rendering, see EDIT5

Comment: I deleted my answer because it didn't make any sense with the current information. ACF does not normally work like that - if the content is being filtered by ACF it does not show in source after switching to wysiwyg mode and then back to source... But apparently your protectedSource prevented the normal operation. That protectedSource statement looks very strange, possibly because I've never used it myself. I thought you had the standard configuration because you hadn't posted it :). Glad you got it sorted out! You can add the solution as an answer yourself

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have some code in my CKeditor config which is causing this behaviour, but not sure why. When I comment it out, my colour coding works. Also I have turned ACF off, as I fine all my inline style attributes gets stripped out. So I have altered my config to :

```
//config.protectedSource.push(/<span[\s\S]*?\>/g); //allows beginning <span> tag - now commented out
//config.protectedSource.push(/<\/span[\s\S]*?\>/g); //allows ending </span> tag - now commented out
config.allowedContent = true; //Added
```